# Facing issues when I try to add a webservice in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I need to consume a web service. that webservice requires user authentication. When I try to add a reference to the web service I'm getting a error saying

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Basic realm="AXIS"'. The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized. If the service is defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Is there any way to get out of this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide the `Credentials` from your Code and also configure the `clientCredentialType` Type and `realm` from you `app.config` file.

follow below steps:

**Step1 :** 
add following set of tags in your `app.config` file.

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
<transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
 realm="AXIS" />
```

**Step 2:**

from your code before accessing the API you need to provide credentials(UserName and Password).

//you must be having below two lines of code already in your code.
Assuming your WebServiceCLient as `ProjectWebServiceClient`

```
ProjectWebServiceClient client;
client = new ProjectWebServiceClient();
```

//Add following two lines of code in your source code:

```
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "yourusername";
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "yourpassword";
```